# PHP Session is being created for every page

Tags: php, session

So problem is as the title says php session is being created for every page. So when I want to get a variable from session like this

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['error'];
```

It says "undefined index".

The problem is, in fact 'error' index defined but not in the current session since php creates new session for every page.

How can I solve this?

Note: I put `session_start();` to every pages' first line, and before `header("location:error.php")` I put `session_write_close();` and after the header there is `die();` method too. I'm working on localhost. Using Latest version of WAMP and JETBRAINS PHPSTORM.

**EDIT---------------------**

This is where I define my session for error(this is from login.php page)

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['error'] = "Enter both username and password";
header('Location:error.php');
exit;
```

When the code above run, a session named "sess_amvrseubtusk0dpuo4fs35r0q1" is created and it has this line in it

```
error|s:32:"Enter both username and password";
```

---

And this is where I want to read session (this is from error.php page)

```
session_start();
echo 'SESSION: ' . $_SESSION['error'];
```

When the code above run, a session named "sess_m08lf25stbhg75gj2h0n0vose0" is created and it is empty.

I have all two of the created session files in my Session directory so 1 session file for each page.

**EDIT 2----------------------------------**

Here my php.ini file
http://pastebin.com/JNsPdzjH

**EDIT 3----------------------------------**

New php.ini file with changes "c:/wamp/tmp" to "C:/Users/nerzid/PhpstormProjects/Deneme/Session"

http://pastebin.com/Zaz37UPC

Comment: If you put session_write_close, means no more data will be stored. If you define "error" variable after that, it will not be stored. Session can be tricky, it must be started at the very first line of the script.

Comment: Do post your "actual" code for the first page, and an example of subsequent pages. I've tested possible scenarios with success. Plus, since you're working off of localhost, make sure the folder is writeable.

Comment: Are you running PHP as a FastCGI application? Sometimes turns out that Fast CGI has not permission access to the sessions folder

Comment: 1- I deleted all of the "session_write_close()" from my code.
2- No, this is not a FastCGI application.

Comment: Also, I created a new directory called Session, to put all of my session files in there. This directory has all of the permissions including write and read.

Answer (score 2):

This posted as per your [**originally posted question**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26441267/2) should people wonder.

---

You may not have defined anything to `$_SESSION['error']`, least not with what you posted for code:

```
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['error'];
```

You would first need to assign something to it.

For example:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['error'] = "Error.";

echo $_SESSION['error'];
```

Then on subsequent pages, you check if the session is set => `isset()` and/or empty => `empty()` or not.

I.e.:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['error']) && !empty($_SESSION['error'])){
echo $_SESSION['error'];
}

else{
echo "Session is not set";
// set a new one
}
```

If session is set from a variable example:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['error'] = "Error.";

$error_x = $_SESSION['error'];

echo $error_x;
```

Also, when using header, add `exit;`

```
header("location:error.php")

exit;
```

always.

---

***Sidenote:***

Since you're working off of localhost, make sure the folder is writeable.

Comment: @Charles That's why I added to check if the session is set, made an edit just now.

Comment: K, so are you saying the error he gets is from when the session error variable has not been set for some reason? is that the reason for your isset?

Comment: @Charles 9 times out of 10, that's what it is.

Comment: Ok, it's like reading troubleshooting section of the manual: - make sure the device is connected, the power button is on...

Comment: @GustavoPinent hehe exactly.

Comment: @Nerzid Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php and http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path - You may have skipped something. I've tested this on my server, and everything checks out. Something in one of your `.ini` files may need to be modified.

Comment: I read both of those 2 pages today twice. This is the reason why I created my own Session directory and put all of my sessions in there. Also I forgot to write, before session_start(); I have 
session_save_path("C:/Users/nerzid/PhpstormProjects/Deneme/Session"); Sessions are created and stored in Session directroy so there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @Nerzid I have to leave but I'll be back later on and will see what else I can do to find what the problem is. If you get an answer before that, let me know.

Comment: I will. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @Nerzid Hi. Well, I've looked at your pastebin `.ini` file, I noticed you did set session path as `c:/wamp/temp` - Did you restart Apache and all services after making those changes? Beyond that, I can't see why it would be failing.

Comment: I uploaded new php.ini file with changes. Only change is "c:/wamp/tmp" to "C:/Users/nerzid/PhpstormProjects/Deneme/Session" .
Still doesnt work and yes I restarted server after every change.